# NY Times full weekly bestseller lists

Tags: data-request, usa, books

Are there any open data compilations of NYT weekly bestseller lists? Other U.S.-centered bestseller lists would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New York Times API

- http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/books_api/

"With the Books API, you can retrieve New York Times book reviews and get data from all best-seller lists. There are two request types within the API: Best Sellers and Book Reviews."